# GET Request on undefined AngularJS expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The AngularJS app that I've built issues GET requests on undefined AngularJS variables.

[image]

job.userPhoto is calculated after a few POST calls so it might take a bit of time to evaluate so I printed it out to make sure it was happening before the GET request is issued. Is there a possible explanation for this? I've read up on dirty checking and handling the error from the interceptor but I'd like to fix the root issue.

EDIT: Just to clarify the image itself is displayed properly, but only after the request for the undefined AngularJS expression is sent.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Does 'ngSrc' fix the issue you are having?